# Failed to open TCP connection to 127.0.0.1:62237

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, rspec, capybara

I am trying to run `RSpec` on a windows machine locally on a basic app checking the `root_path` has the text `Hello world!` on it

my `gemfile` includes the following:

```rb
group :development, :test do
  gem "debug", platforms: %i[ mri mingw x64_mingw ]
  # The RSpec testing framework
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'webdrivers'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
end
```

I have checked that I have the most current version of `chrome` and `chrome drivers` installed locally and have also changed these out with earlier releases with no luck.

```rb
# hello_world_spec.rb

require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe 'Hello world', type: :system do
  describe 'index page' do
    it 'shows the right content' do
      visit root_path
      expect(page).to have_content('Hello, world!')
    end
  end
end
```

```rb
# index.html.erb
Hello, world!
```

When I run `rspec`, it fires chrome up but gets stuck on following:

[image: Chrome image]

and `RSpec` errors in `powershell` with the following:

```
C:\Users\Me\code\selenium> rspec

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:62231/devtools/browser/069d4174-208d-4b46-a89c-199d35939c8d
[10180:7704:1113/171936.126:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(215)] [17:19:36.126] Bluetooth: bluetooth_adapter_winrt.cc:1074 Getting Default Adapter failed.

Failures:

  1) Hello world index page shows the right content
     Got 0 failures and 2 other errors:

     1.1) Failure/Error: visit root_path

          Net::OpenTimeout:
            Failed to open TCP connection to 127.0.0.1:62237 (A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. - user specified timeout)
          # ./spec/hello_world_spec.rb:6:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
          # ------------------
          # --- Caused by: ---
          # Errno::ETIMEDOUT:
          #   A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. - user specified timeout
          #   ./spec/hello_world_spec.rb:6:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

     1.2) Failure/Error:
            raise e, "Failed to open TCP connection to " +
              "#{conn_addr}:#{conn_port} (#{e.message})"

          Net::OpenTimeout:
            Failed to open TCP connection to 127.0.0.1:62251 (A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. - user specified timeout)
          # c:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/net/http.rb:1001:in `rescue in connect'
          # c:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/net/http.rb:997:in `connect'
          # c:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/net/http.rb:976:in `do_start'
          # c:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/net/http.rb:965:in `start'
          # c:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/net/http.rb:627:in `start'
          # c:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/capybara-3.38.0/lib/capybara/server/checker.rb:36:in `make_request'
          # c:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/capybara-3.38.0/lib/capybara/server/checker.rb:28:in `http_request'
          # c:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/capybara-3.38.0/lib/capybara/server/checker.rb:14:in `request'
          # c:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/capybara-3.38.0/lib/capybara/server.rb:56:in `responsive?'
          # c:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/capybara-3.38.0/lib/capybara/server.rb:73:in `boot'
          # c:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/capybara-3.38.0/lib/capybara/session.rb:94:in `initialize'
          # c:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/capybara-3.38.0/lib/capybara.rb:421:in `new'
          # c:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/capybara-3.38.0/lib/capybara.rb:421:in `block in session_pool'
          # c:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/capybara-3.38.0/lib/capybara.rb:317:in `current_session'
          # c:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/capybara-3.38.0/lib/capybara/dsl.rb:46:in `page'
          # c:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/system_testing/test_helpers/screenshot_helper.rb:99:in `save_image'
          # c:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/system_testing/test_helpers/screenshot_helper.rb:36:in `take_screenshot'
          # c:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/system_testing/test_helpers/screenshot_helper.rb:45:in `take_failed_screenshot'
          # c:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/system_testing/test_helpers/setup_and_teardown.rb:8:in `before_teardown'
          # c:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rspec-rails-6.0.1/lib/rspec/rails/example/system_example_group.rb:110:in `call'
          # c:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rspec-rails-6.0.1/lib/rspec/rails/example/system_example_group.rb:110:in `block (2 levels) in <module:SystemExampleGroup>'
          # c:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.12.0/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:457:in `instance_exec'
          # c:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.12.0/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:457:in `instance_exec'
          # c:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.12.0/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:372:in `run'
          # c:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.12.0/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:529:in `block in run_owned_hooks_for'
          # c:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.12.0/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:528:in `each'
          # c:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.12.0/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:528:in `run_owned_hooks_for'
          # c:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.12.0/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:615:in `block in run_example_hooks_for'
          # c:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.12.0/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:614:in `each'
          # c:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.12.0/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:614:in `run_example_hooks_for'
          # c:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.12.0/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:485:in `run'
          # c:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.12.0/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:518:in `run_after_example'
          # c:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.12.0/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:283:in `block in run'
          # c:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.12.0/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:511:in `block in with_around_and_singleton_context_hooks'
          # c:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.12.0/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:468:in `block in with_around_example_hooks'
          # c:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.12.0/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:486:in `block in run'
          # c:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.12.0/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:626:in `block in run_around_example_hooks_for'
          # c:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.12.0/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:352:in `call'
          # c:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rspec-rails-6.0.1/lib/rspec/rails/example/system_example_group.rb:120:in `block (2 levels) in <module:SystemExampleGroup>'
          # c:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.12.0/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:457:in `instance_exec'
          # c:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.12.0/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:457:in `instance_exec'
          # c:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.12.0/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:390:in `execute_with'
          # c:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.12.0/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:628:in `block (2 levels) in run_around_example_hooks_for'
          # c:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.12.0/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:352:in `call'
          # c:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rspec-rails-6.0.1/lib/rspec/rails/adapters.rb:75:in `block (2 levels) in <module:MinitestLifecycleAdapter>'
          # c:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.12.0/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:457:in `instance_exec'
          # c:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.12.0/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:457:in `instance_exec'
          # c:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.12.0/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:390:in `execute_with'
          # c:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.12.0/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:628:in `block (2 levels) in run_around_example_hooks_for'
          # c:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.12.0/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:352:in `call'
          # c:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.12.0/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:629:in `run_around_example_hooks_for'
          # c:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.12.0/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:486:in `run'
          # c:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.12.0/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:468:in `with_around_example_hooks'
          # c:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.12.0/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:511:in `with_around_and_singleton_context_hooks'
          # c:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.12.0/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:259:in `run'
          # c:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.12.0/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:646:in `block in run_examples'
          # c:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.12.0/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:642:in `map'
          # c:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.12.0/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:642:in `run_examples'
          # c:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.12.0/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:607:in `run'
          # c:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.12.0/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:608:in `block in run'
          # c:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.12.0/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:608:in `map'
          # c:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.12.0/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:608:in `run'
          # c:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.12.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:121:in `block (3 levels) in run_specs'
          # c:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.12.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:121:in `map'
          # c:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.12.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:121:in `block (2 levels) in run_specs'
          # c:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.12.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:2070:in `with_suite_hooks'
          # c:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.12.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:116:in `block in run_specs'
          # c:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.12.0/lib/rspec/core/reporter.rb:74:in `report'
          # c:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.12.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:115:in `run_specs'
          # c:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.12.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:89:in `run'
          # c:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.12.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:71:in `run'
          # c:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.12.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:45:in `invoke'
          # c:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.12.0/exe/rspec:4:in `<top (required)>'
          # c:/Ruby31-x64/bin/rspec:32:in `load'
          # c:/Ruby31-x64/bin/rspec:32:in `<main>'
          # 
          #   Showing full backtrace because every line was filtered out.
          #   See docs for RSpec::Configuration#backtrace_exclusion_patterns and
          #   RSpec::Configuration#backtrace_inclusion_patterns for more information.
          # ------------------
          # --- Caused by: ---
          # Errno::ETIMEDOUT:
          #   A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. - user specified timeout
          #   c:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/socket.rb:61:in `connect_internal'

Finished in 2 minutes 3.2 seconds (files took 5.29 seconds to load)
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/hello_world_spec.rb:5 # Hello world index page shows the right content
```